# Rotate and translate object in local and global orientation using glm

Tags: c++, opengl, math, rotation, glm-math

i am trying to implement functions, where i can rotate/ translate an object in local or global orientation, like in 3D modeling software, using glm. Something like this:

```
void Rotate(float x, float y, float z, bool localOrientation);
```

but I dont know how to get it working. Local rotation rotation should just be something like this(?):

```
m_Orientation *= glm::rotate(x, glm::vec3(1,0,0);
m_Orientation *= glm::rotate(y, glm::vec3(0,1,0);
m_Orientation *= glm::rotate(z, glm::vec3(0,0,1);

// (m_Orientation is glm::mat4)
```

But how to combine this with local orientation? Actually i need to rotate the rotation matrix in world orientation, right?
I hope you know what i mean with local and global oriented rotation/translation, like it is in 3D modeling programs. In most of them you have a button to switch between local and global.

And how would i calculating the forward/right/up vector then?
normally it should be something like this, right?:

```
forward = m_Orientation * glm::vec4(0,0,-1,0);
```

I tried global rotation with this:

```
m_GlobalOrientation = glm::rotate(m_GlobalRotation.x, glm::vec(1,0,0);
m_GlobalOrientation *= glm::rotate(m_GlobalRotation.y, glm::vec(0,1,0);
m_GlobalOrientation *= glm::rotate(m_GlobalRotation.z, glm::vec(0,0,1);
```

but then only x rotation is in global orientation, y and z rotation is in local orientation, since it is already rotated around x axis. So I need to rotate all 3 angles at once(?)

Translating local should just be adding translation values to current translation, and local translation should be glm::inverse(m_Orientation) * translationVector right?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Before I come to your question, let me explain some core concepts of matrices.

Assume that we have the following matrix:

[image: Matrix]

wher `T` is a translation and `R` is a rotation matrix.

When we use this matrix to transform a vertex (or even mesh), there is one unique result. However, we can get to this result with the help of two interpretations:

**Interpretation 1: Evaluate from right to left**

If we evaluate the matrix from right to left, all transformations are performed in the global coordinate system. So if we transform a triangle that sits at the origin, we get the following result:

[image: Transformation from right to left]

**Interpretation 2: Evaluate from left to right**

In the other case, all transformations are performed in the local coordinate system:

[image: Transformation from left to right]

Of course, we get the same result.

So coming back to your question. If you store the position and orientation of the object as a matrix `T`. You can rotate this object in its local coordinate system by multiplying a rotation matrix to the right side of the current matrix. And in the global system by multiplying it at the left side. The same applies for translation:

```
void Rotate(float x, float y, float z, bool localOrientation) 
{
    auto rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(x, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
    rotationMatrix  *= glm::rotate(y, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
    rotationMatrix  *= glm::rotate(z, glm::vec3(0,0,1));
    if(localOrientation)
        this->T = this->T * rotationMatrix;
    else
        this->T = rotationMatrix * this->T;
}
```

The right / forward / up vectors are the column vectors of the matrix `T`. You can either read them directly or get them by multiplying the matrix with `(1, 0, 0, 0)` (right), `(0, 1, 0, 0)` (up), `(0, 0, 1, 0)` (for/backward) or `(0, 0, 0, 1)` (position).

If you want to read more about this, take a look at my [blog article about matrices in DirectX](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/directx-and-matrices/). But it's for DirectX, which uses transposed matrices. Therefore the matrix order is reversed. Watch out for that when reading the article.

Comment: Wow, this is one great explanation! Now I know what people mean with left and right multiplication. Thank you, i will try it out!

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much, i had trouble with this for weeks. You helped me understanding the matrix multiplication better, especially because of the code sample ( i learn better from code x) )!