# GLM OpenGL Rotation only correct around X axis

Tags: rotation, quaternions, glm-math

I'm using this very simple code to rotate objects around their own origin

```
void Entity::rotate(unsigned short axis, float speed, float delta)
{
    m_Orientation[axis] += delta * speed;
    glm::quat quaternion = glm::quat(glm::vec3(m_Orientation[0], m_Orientation[1], m_Orientation[2]));

    m_RotationMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(quaternion);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the rotation is only relative to object's direction on the **X** axis. Meaning that no matter which way the object is facing (what it's orientation is), if I rotate it around **X** it will always rotate around it's own **X** axis. That is what I would like to do, but on the other 2 axis as well.

But Y and Z always rotate around world X and Y axis, disregarding which way my object is facing.

My code is so small and simple I don't really see the problem? Is the X rotation being always correct the accident, or is it that the other two are wrong?

Comment: Here's a video of the issue: youtube.com / watch?v=DCZJsm8tZA8

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try this:

```
#include <glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp>
/**
If you change speed to a vec3,
it do all the calculations at once
(you won't have to do it for each angle)
**/

void Entity::rotate(glm::vec3 speed, float delta) 
{
   rotation = speed * data
   m_modelMatrix *= glm::eulerAngleXYZ(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);
}
```

The glm::eulerAngleXYZ function will take the angles and create a rotation matrix from it.

But be aware of [gimbal lock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

If you do your multiplication of the matrix from right to left, it will rotate around the global axis. If you do it the other way, it will rotate around the local axis.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, however I'm getting the exact same result using eulerAngleYXZ... X is still correct, Y and Z are still rotating around global X and Y axis, not local :(

Comment: I'm not doing any matrix multiplication? Apart from Translation * Rotation * Scale to get the modelmatrix

Comment: You have to do it like that : translation * rotation * scale * rotationAroundLocalAxis

Comment: I've added a video on youtube to demonstrate the issue: youtube.com / watch?v=DCZJsm8tZA8 - I've also tried glm::rotate multiplying the separate axis but that still won't give me the desired result... maybe I need to separately calculate the up & side vectors and somehow add those to the calculation? Or I'm not sure, please someone help!

Comment: Calculate the model matrix once and each frame, multiply it by glm::eulerAngleYXZ(...) like in the answer. If you don't understand, please take a look at https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923482/rotate-and-translate-object-in-local-and-global-orientation-using-glm&ved=0ahUKEwiv5eHqs4XQAhUCahoKHefTCBoQFggnMAE&usg=AFQjCNEXiSge2-oUIM5oMna3W8bk_wyXFw&sig2=B0KZtYmBRdYtml4y3mAzYg (sorry for the long link). Be sure to not reset the matrix and to have the rotation matrix at the right of the multiplication.