# Combine rotations in 3D

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation

i'm trying to implement 3D rotation with openGL(C++), 
I was really tired of searching for a way to rotate any object around the global (X, Y, Z) not the local one.

i found this easy concept:

1. Get the local to world transformation matrix of the object you want to rotate.
2. Use the inverse of this matrix to convert the world axis to local coordinates.
3. Use the converted axis to compute the rotation as you are doing in the code.

so i made something like :

```
 //set the rotation matrix ti identity matrix
    transformedModel->rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), float(0), glm::vec3(1, 1, 1) ); //rotation matrix = identity matrix


    //X-axis
    glm::vec4 axis = glm::inverse(transformedModel->rotationMatrix) * glm::vec4(1,0,0,0);
    axis = glm::normalize(axis);
    transformedModel->rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(transformedModel->rotationMatrix, glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::vec3(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z));
    //Y-axis
    glm::vec4 axis2 = glm::inverse(transformedModel->rotationMatrix) * glm::vec4(0,1,0,0);
    transformedModel->rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(transformedModel->rotationMatrix, glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::vec3(axis2.x, axis2.y, axis2.z));
    axis2 = glm::normalize(axis2);
    //Z-axis
    glm::vec4 axis3 = glm::inverse(transformedModel->rotationMatrix) * glm::vec4(0,0,1,0);
    axis3 = glm::normalize(axis3);
    transformedModel->rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(transformedModel->rotationMatrix, glm::radians(rotation.z), glm::vec3(axis3.x, axis3.y, axis3.z));


    updateModelMatrix(transformedModel);
```

it works fine in special cases not at all!!
can any one help me to get the simplest right method to do that?

Comment: If you want to rotate in the global system, just multiply the rotation matrix to the left of the original matrix. Multiplying to the right results in a rotation in the local system (assuming column vectors).

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by the original matrix ? 


my modelMatrix = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * scalingMatrix ;


where rotation = Rx * Ry * Rz;


then i send to the vertex shader : 


MVP = projection*view*modelMatrix ;

Comment: Then just change this to `modelMatrix = RotationMatrix * TranslationMatrix * ScalingMatrix`. This will rotate in the global coordinate system. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, imagine i rotated my object 90 around X-axis , then if i rotated it around Y-axis relative to me, i will find it rotate around Y-axis relative to it which is Z-axis for me !

Comment: Then do `Rz * Ry * Rx`.

Comment: what about if i started with Z-axis ? i will face the same problem ! the object will rotate around it's own new coordinates not around global X,Y,Z

Comment: Well, you have to decide for one order. It's just not possible to get everything at the same time.

Comment: i think 'quaternion' do ! but i can't figure it out yet ! anyway i'm trying

Comment: No, quaternions will not help you here. It's a conceptual question on how to compose rotations. Not on how to represent them. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923482/rotate-and-translate-object-in-local-and-global-orientation-using-glm/22076364#22076364) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, determine the point to rotate the object around. This is often the object's center. We'll call this the rotation point.

Now, for each vertex in the object, we would perform the following operation:

**1)** Translate the vertex to the origin. This can be done by subtracting the rotation point from the vertex. Eg, if the rotation point is (5, 10, 20), we would subtract 5 from the vertex's x-coordinate, 10 from the vertex's y-coordinate, and 20 from the vertex's z-coordinate.

**2)** Perform the rotation with a 3x3 rotation matrix.

**3)** Translate the vertex back to the rotation point. We undo the first step, and add 5, 10, and 20 to the vertex's coordinates.

I find this simpler than using a transformation matrix, but it may be less efficient.

Comment: i prefer to not deal with vertices, just want to send a matrix to vertex shader to be applied on all vertices