# Rotate object with keys

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew, opengl-3

I've written a code below to rotate the cube, but it rotates not correctly. I need to keep my view matrix without changing, but I can't guess how to do it.

Code:

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP) 
    {
        model = rotate(model, 0.08f, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        model = rotate(model, 0.08f, vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        model = rotate(model, 0.08f, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        model = rotate(model, 0.08f, vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does *not rotating correctly* mean?

Comment: @NicoSchertler , for instace:  when I rotate the cube down, then rigth, and if i wanna rotate it up again, it turns other direction, because model matrix has been changed.

Comment: If you want the global view, then calculate the rotation matrix and multiply it from the left side to `model`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler where should I multiply it? At the end of the function or in the IF construction? I must make extra matrix, then rotate it and multiply it with model afterwards?

Comment: In the `if` bodies. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076364/1210053).

Comment: @NicoSchertler , extra matrix really helps me! Thank you!