# After translating shape doesn't rotate around it's origin

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am developing an analogue of OpenGL. So I have model, view and projection matrices.

Scaling and rotating work pefectly without translating. But when I apply translating to object and trying to rotate it again - it rotates around world origin.

I know that transformation operations should come in next order: scaling -> rotating -> translating. But I don't understand how to do it with only one matrix (model).

So, how can I do it in the right way? Should I use 3 matrices insted?

My work with matrices:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; ++i)
        {
            float[,] vertexCoords = { { vertices[i].SX }, { vertices[i].SY }, { vertices[i].SZ }, { vertices[i].SW } };

            var modelViewMatrix = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(camera.ViewMatrix, shape.ModelMatrix);
            var eyeCoordinates = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(modelViewMatrix, vertexCoords);
            var clipCoordinates = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(camera.ProjectionMatrix, eyeCoordinates);


            var ndc = new float[,] {
                { clipCoordinates[0, 0] / clipCoordinates[3, 0] },
                { clipCoordinates[1, 0] / clipCoordinates[3, 0] },
                { clipCoordinates[2, 0] / clipCoordinates[3, 0] },
                { clipCoordinates[3, 0]}
            };

            var windowCoordinates = new float[,] { 
                { 640 / 2 * ndc[0, 0] + (640 / 2) },
                { 360 / 2 * ndc[1, 0] + (360 / 2) },
                { (50 - (-50)) / 2 * ndc[2, 0] + (50 + (-50)) / 2 },
                { ndc[3, 0]}
            };

            SetNewCoordinatesToPoint(vertices[i], windowCoordinates);             
        }
```

Rotation algorithm example:

```
private void RotateZ(MCommonPrimitive shape, double angle)
    {
        double rads = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;

        float[,] rotateZ = {
            { (float)Math.Cos(rads), -(float)Math.Sin(rads), 0, 0 },
            { (float)Math.Sin(rads), (float)Math.Cos(rads), 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
        };

        shape.ModelMatrix = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(rotateZ, shape.ModelMatrix);
    }
```

MatrixMultiplier:

```
public static class MatrixMultiplier
{
    public static float[,] MultiplyMatrix(float[,] a, float[,] b)
    {
        float[,] c = null;

        if (a.GetLength(1) == b.GetLength(0))
        {
            c = new float[a.GetLength(0), b.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    c[i, j] = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < a.GetLength(1); k++) // OR k<b.GetLength(0)
                        c[i, j] = c[i, j] + a[i, k] * b[k, j];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Number of columns in First Matrix should be equal to Number of rows in Second Matrix.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n Please re-enter correct dimensions.");
            throw new ArithmeticException("Number of columns in First Matrix should be equal to Number of rows in Second Matrix");
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's all a matter of order. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923482/rotate-and-translate-object-in-local-and-global-orientation-using-glm/22076364#22076364).

Comment: @NicoSchertler wow, this really helped me a lot. Now shape rotates around it's origin. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to write an answer to this question or delete it altogether then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Nico Schertler's original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923482/rotate-and-translate-object-in-local-and-global-orientation-using-glm/22076364#22076364) it all depends on matrices multiplication order. So, for example, if I will use this code

```
shape.ModelMatrix = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(rotateZ, shape.ModelMatrix);
```

from my RotateZ method, shape will rotate around world origin. And, if I change my code to this:

```
shape.ModelMatrix = MatrixMultiplier.MultiplyMatrix(shape.ModelMatrix, rotateZ);
```

shape will rotate around it's center.

Answer (score 2):

> But when I apply translating to object and trying to rotate it again - it rotates around world origin.

Yes, that's how it works. *You have to rotate the object first, then translate it to the desired position.* Geometric transformations are not commutative, i.e. the order of operations matter.