# What to multiply object R matrix with when rotating around global Z axis

Tags: graphics

I have an object that I rotate using its local coordinate system (modelspace). I then render an image using a camera located right above the object in world coordinate (0,0,+z). I then render an image and want to do inplane rotation (i.e. rotating the image i rendered). What do I need to multiply the object (modelspace) rotation matrix with in order to get a correct rotation matrix for the in plane rotated object that has been rotated x degrees?

Comment: Put an according rotation matrix between the view/projection matrix and the model matrix.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not quite understand your answer. This problem is given that I only have access to a set of images and how the model is rotated and where in world space the camera is located and its orientation so to say. Some more elaboration with equations would help a lot, I am a slow learner. Sorry.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. If you are rotating the model by some amount about the principal axis, the image rotates by the same amount.

Comment: Imagine that i have an object that i rotate around its local axis. I then rotate the rendered object around the global z axis, thus the entire local coordinate system will rotate. How will this global rotation change the local rotation matrix? That is, I am looking for the rotation matrix for the object in its local space that makes the object end up in the same orientation as if I where to rotate the object and then rotate the rendered image around the z axis.

Comment: Multiply the rotation matrix from the other side that you would use for local rotation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076364/1210053).