# What is the correct order of Transformations when calculating Matrices in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation, glm-math

I am following the tutorials at LearnOpenGL.com and I am confused about the order of Matrices.

The [Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations) chapter tells:

> Matrix multiplication is not commutative, which means their order is important. When multiplying matrices the right-most matrix is first multiplied with the vector so you should read the multiplications from right to left. It is advised to first do scaling operations, then rotations and lastly translations when combining matrices otherwise they might (negatively) affect each other. For example, if you would first do a translation and then scale, the translation vector would also scale!

So If I am not wrong, the order is `Translate * Rotate * Scale * vector_to_transform`.

But immediately in the next Chapter, when calculating the LookAt matrix, the multiplication order is flipped. Here is the code snippet from the website:

```
// Custom implementation of the LookAt function
glm::mat4 calculate_lookAt_matrix(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 target, glm::vec3 worldUp)
{
    // 1. Position = known
    // 2. Calculate cameraDirection
    glm::vec3 zaxis = glm::normalize(position - target);
    // 3. Get positive right axis vector
    glm::vec3 xaxis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(glm::normalize(worldUp), zaxis));
    // 4. Calculate camera up vector
    glm::vec3 yaxis = glm::cross(zaxis, xaxis);

    // Create translation and rotation matrix
    // In glm we access elements as mat[col][row] due to column-major layout
    glm::mat4 translation = glm::mat4(1.0f); // Identity matrix by default
    translation[3][0] = -position.x; // Third column, first row
    translation[3][1] = -position.y;
    translation[3][2] = -position.z;
    glm::mat4 rotation = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    rotation[0][0] = xaxis.x; // First column, first row
    rotation[1][0] = xaxis.y;
    rotation[2][0] = xaxis.z;
    rotation[0][1] = yaxis.x; // First column, second row
    rotation[1][1] = yaxis.y;
    rotation[2][1] = yaxis.z;
    rotation[0][2] = zaxis.x; // First column, third row
    rotation[1][2] = zaxis.y;
    rotation[2][2] = zaxis.z; 

    // Return lookAt matrix as combination of translation and rotation matrix
    return rotation * translation; // Remember to read from right to left (first translation then rotation)
}
```

At the end of the code snippet, the matrix is calculated as `rotation * translation`, even though the matrix is going to be multiplied as,

```
gl_position = projection * lookAt * model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

as Column-major matrices must be pre-multiplied to the vector.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: There is no correct order - you always apply matrices in the order that is most suited for your problem (see e.g. [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076364/1210053)). The LookAt matrix is a bit special in that it is somewhat inverse. That can be a reason why the code uses `rotation * translation`. But it always depends on how you derive the formula. You can also use `translation * rotation` if you calculate the translation a bit differently.

Comment: @NicoSchertler So it's just the View Matrix that's a special case? And by your answer, the final result should be the same. But I get a different result when I flip the order.

Comment: You need a different translation matrix if you want to flip the order.

Comment: Okay! I think I got the gist.  I missed an important detail: the View matrix should not scale stuff. So it's just a Matrix to rotate and translate the model matrix. To do so, the matrix should be combined in a particular way. As you mentioned, the view matrix is kind of a special case. See the `Combining Matrices` section of  [Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations) chapter.

Comment: the rotation * translation is perfectly correct.
The camera transform can be seen as an *inverse model transform*.
3D Math doesn't care if you move the camera before the objects or the objects in front of the camera. 

Let's assume the model transform is
M = T*R*S,
(we leave out the scaling ) you want the inverse transform, so 
C = M^-1 = (T*R)^-1 = R^-1 * T^-1 = R^T * T(-t) (inverse of an orthonormal matrix is it's transpose, inverse of translation is the inverse of the translation-vector-komponents)
Which is exactly the matrix you are returning in your lookAt method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LearnOpenGL unfortunately doesn't explain where the Camera transform comes from.
You can see the Camera transform as an inverse model transform.
3D math doesn't care if you move the camera towards the Objects or the Objects towards the Camera.
Also if your objects are already scaled to have the proper "World Space" size you don't need the camera to scale them. The scaling for the "intrinsic Camera Parameters" are dealt with in the projection matrix (scale for aspect ration and field of view). Which is done after the Camera transform.

So we move the object points towards the "camera" instead of the camera towards the points. As I said you would not leave the scaling in the Camera Matrix, since you only want to orient the objects in front of the Camera.

Placing the Camera as Model in the world space would be:

```
M = TR   (leave out S for above reasons)
```

Then you inverse the Camera Transform ->

```
C = M^-1           | M = TR
  = (TR)^-1 
  = R^-1 * T^-1    | inverse of matrix product -> flip order and invert matrices
```

Lets assume R(angle) is the Matrix that rotates by angle angle and T(t) is the Matrix that translates by vector t then:

```
  = R(angle)^-1 * T(t)^-1
  = R^T(angle) * T(-t)
```

Which is exactly what you return in your lookAt-method. The basis vectors of R are set up by the column vectors of you new coordinate frame, but then transposed (so you have them as row vectors). That's because the camera frame vectors are orthogonal and unit length, so the resulting matrix is "orthonomal" which means it's inverse is it's transpose. And the inverse Translation Matrix T(t) gets the translation vector T(-t) (inverse of eye-Position of the Camera).
Hope my explanation clearifies more than it confuses :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay! After reading through the entire chapter again, I missed a crucial detail. The View matrix usually does not scale the objects. It's just a matrix to rotate and translate the model matrix in such a way to simulate an eye into the world. [This chapter](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations) of LearnOpenGL.com has a block explaining about combining matrices and it shows how to combine a translate and rotate matric and it's how the `lookAt` function is implemented.